# this method or property cannot be called on null values. data is null

Tags: c#

When I call the function I receive an error that says `data is null. This method or property cannot be called on null values.`

I believe the error exists at this line 
    `Error = id = rd.GetString(0);`

The code I am using is below

```
public string MaxId()
{
   string id="";
   con.Open();
   string sql = "SELECT MAX(CustID) FROM Customer";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
   SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while(rd.Read())
   {
      id = rd.GetString(0);
   }
   con.Close();
   return id;
}
```

How do I get a string from the DataReader that may be null?

Comment: You are try to get a probably `integer` value with `GetString` method. I assume your `CustID` column is some integer type.. Check out [SqlDataReader Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) And please accept answers if they solved your problem..

Comment: The downvotes and close votes seem a little harsh.  While the question could be expressed more clearly, it's fairly obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your Customer table is empty, then the query will return NULL.

In this case `rd.GetString(0)` will throw, since `GetString` can not return a NULL value.

You could do something like:

```
if (rd.IsDBNull(0))
{
    id = null;
}
else
{
    id = rd.GetString(0);
}
```

Comment: also --> see @Soner's comment about the hole string/int problem

Comment: @JensKloster - there's nothing in the question to say whether the CustID field is a string, integer, or something else (long, guid, ...).  If it's not a string, there'll be a different error to the one the OP described.

Comment: oh yeah- you are right. I confussed it with `COUNT` which always returns a number